# PDO::bindParam in a foreach loop, all values are being set as the same?

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, pdo

I am trying to make life a little bit easier for repeated database calls with the a function which should (in theory) allow me to bind parameters using an array:

```
    function query($tblName,$queryParams = false){
    $this->queryObject = $this->con->prepare($this->queryString);
    if($queryParams){
        foreach ($queryParams as $key => $value) {
            $this->queryObject->bindParam($key, $value);
        }
    }
    $this->queryResult = $this->queryObject->execute();
    print_r($this->queryResult);
}
```

Which I am then calling like so:

```
$queryParams = array(':userName' => $_POST['username'], ':password' => $_POST['password'], ':salt'=>$userUser->salt, ':userEmail'=>$_POST['email']);
$registrationDb->query('tblUser', $queryParams);
```

The database connection is working, and there is a write being made, however, all the values are being set to `$_POST['email]`, and I can't puzzle out why this is happening.

Is there a better way to be doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`bindParam` binds variable by reference, so you need `bindValue` instead:

```
$this->queryObject->bindValue($key, $value);
```