# Foreaching PDO bindValue / BindParam

Tags: php, pdo, foreach, bindvalue

I wanted to make my life a bit easier like in this post:

[PDO::bindParam in a foreach loop, all values are being set as the same?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12343891/pdobindparam-in-a-foreach-loop-all-values-are-being-set-as-the-same)

And several others...

I tried several variants to get my code work (to see messages) but no result i have to methods in my class:

```
public function getMessages($locationId, $name) {
    if(!empty($name)) {

        $query = 'SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM sms WHERE location_id=:locationId ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5) AS SOURCE ORDER BY id ASC';
        $parameters = array(':locationId' => $locationId);

        $row = $this->returnDataObject($query, $parameters);

        while ($row) {
            $this->fetchData($row, $biggestId, $name);
        }

        $this->updateSessionKey($locationId, $name);
    }
}
```

And the other:

```
public function returnDataObject($query, $parameters) {
    var_dump($query); 
    var_dump($parameters);

    $dataObject = $this->dbh->prepare($query);

    foreach ($parameters as $key => &$value) {
        $dataObject->bindParam($key, $value);
    }

    $dataObject->execute();
    $row = $dataObject->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    return $row;
```

}

I tried:

```
foreach ($parameters as $key => &$value) {
and:
foreach ($parameters as $key => $value) {
```

I tried:

```
$dataObject->bindParam($key, $value);
and:
$dataObject->bindValue($key, $value);
```

I also tried in getMessages method to die('I am in getMessages method');
But i couldn't get that far...

What should i do differently to get this code work?

I appreciate any help!

---

EDIT:

My bad with biggestId but declaring biggestId:

```
$biggestId = $this->getBiggestId($locationId);
```

But fixing that didn't fix the whole problem. This first method works perfictly if it is:

```
public function getMessages($locationId, $name) {
    if(!empty($name)) {
        $biggestId = $this->getBiggestId($locationId);

        $messages = $this->dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM sms WHERE location_id=:locationId ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5) AS SOURCE ORDER BY id ASC');
        $messages->bindParam(':locationId', $locationId);
        $messages->execute();

        while ($row = $messages->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
            $this->fetchData($row, $biggestId, $name);
        }

        $_SESSION[$name] = $biggestId;
    }
}
```

But i want to use the method so i don't have to bindParam / BindValue manualy, the functionality of returnDataObject method would make my life easier...

Comment: Where does biggestId come from ?  Shouldnt it be locationId? You should also use fetchAll because you need the array

Comment: I fixed that bad, but this wasn't the reason of the big problem. The method returnDataObject still doesn't work... My code works perfectly without using this method but method would make my life easier...

Comment: fetchData cause no problem, beause without using returnDataObject it worked as it is...

Answer (score 2):

Make the following Changes:

- use `fetchAll()` instead of `fetch()`
- Since `fetchAll()` is used, use a `foreach` rather than a `while` loop.

**returnDataObject:**

```
public function returnDataObject($query, $parameters) {
    $dataObject = $this->dbh->prepare($query);

    foreach ($parameters as $key => &$value) {
        $dataObject->bindParam($key, $value);
    }

    $dataObject->execute();
    $rows = $dataObject->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    return $rows;
}
```

**getMessages:**

```
public function getMessages($locationId, $name) {
    if(!empty($name)) {

        $query = 'SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM sms WHERE location_id=:locationId ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5) AS SOURCE ORDER BY id ASC';
        $parameters = array(':locationId' => $locationId);

        $rows = $this->returnDataObject($query, $parameters);

        foreach($rows as $row) {
            $this->fetchData($row, $biggestId, $name);
        }

        $this->updateSessionKey($locationId, $name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Absolutly perfect all functionallity works! Thanks a lot! Now i have this method...

Comment: @user2812532 you are welcome, remember to approve my answer ;)